# Is there a way to override a media query with :checked pseudo-class?

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

This is my html code. A div with ".menu" class returns from wp_nav_menu() function.

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="mobile-menu-check" name="mobile">
  <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'container_class' => 'menu' ) ); ?>
```

And there is my css code. What I am trying to accomplish is hide menu if screen width is lower than 600px but make it visible again after triggering input.

```
.menu { float: right; display: block;}

input:checked + .menu { display: block!important; }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .menu { display: none; }
}
```

My problem here is clicking on input doesn't reveal div. I checked on chrome inspect and I can see that css works but, still div doesn't show up. Is there an order that I should apply on css for make it work? I searched but couldn't find anything about media queries overrides.

Comment: Could we see the HTML rendered output? Also, please note that media queries do not increase specificity, so you can move your `input` test after the media query and remove the `!important`.

Comment: You can do `input:not(:checked) + .menu { display: none!important; }` inside the media query, I think it should work

Comment: @AlonEitan that worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.